# Parsing date string to int using cpp

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve a problem. The Problem is : There is given a date string like **21/9/2013**. I have to convert this date into **int**. I have used `stoi` but it is just showed first two int **21**.

Comment: What is the int supposed to represent ?  Eg what int value would you want to produce given your example date?

Comment: The output should be
21
9
2013

Comment: That’s three ints

Comment: yes that's three int only

Comment: What exactly are you supposed to return? As Jeremy said, 21 9 2013 is three ints, not one int. C++ doesn't let you return 3 ints. Do you want to return a string of these three ints? An array of 3 ints? Do you want to print 21 9 2013 to the console?

Comment: @jdabtieu I want to print 21 9 2013 to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to print 21 9 2013 to the console

So you don't really need three integers. You need three strings.

With these includes:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
```

You can parse a string like this:

```
string date = "21/9/2013";
```

into its components, like this:

```
stringstream stream(date);
string s;
while (std::getline(stream, s, '/') {
    cout << s << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

The above should print out: `21 9 2013`

If you really want integers, the above shouldn't be too hard to modify. You can use stoi on each iteration of the while loop above.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is *tokenize* the string into three different substrings ("21", "9", and "2013"); then you can call `stoi()` on each substring and print out the integer `stoi()` returned for each one.

There are various ways to tokenize a string in C++; rather than choose one to repeat here, I'll just link to the [StackOverflow question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c) on that topic.